# Google like login process

Tags: amazon-web-services, single-sign-on, amazon-cognito

I would like to implement Google like login features in my products… like once you register on Gmail you don’t need to register for Youtube or drive..Can Amazon cognito will help me?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a technology known as `single sign-on`
You can use user `Gmail`, `Facebook` etc ids to sign up for your system and then you can authenticate across all you application.

if you don't want to use Gmail, Facebook then you should go ahead for `OpenID`

You can read about OpenID [here](http://openid.net/what-is-openid/)

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Cognito does provide Single Sign On if you rely on the domain created for your user pool. So if the authentication for all the products is happening from that domain, you can achieve SSO with different redirect_uri pointing to different products.